# How can I make link background transparent?

Tags: html, css, styling

I inherited some design css from another designer and I am having trouble figuring out what they are doing.

This is the site: http://www.problemio.com and in the blue bar towards the top, there is text like "problems support" ..

Right now it has these awkward-looking blue boxes there. On mouse over on the word problems, it shows nice-looking dropdowns.

If I get rid of the awkward-looking blue boxes, it messes up the styling for the nice dropdown. Any idea how I can make the boxes not appear at all, but still keep the nice mouse-over-dropdown effect?

Here is my css file:

```
.menusystem 
{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.menusystem ul, .menusystem li 
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.menusystem li 
{
    list-style: none outside none;
}

.menusystem ul 
{
    list-style: none;
/*
    -moz-border-radius: 14px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
*/

}

.menusystem ul li 
{
    position: relative;
/*
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -moz-border-radius: 14px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
*/
}

.menusystem ul li ul 
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.6em;
    right: 0;
    width: 10em;    
}

.menusystem li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
     /* dark blue */
/*  border: 1px solid #2e6ea4; */
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menusystem ul li.main_menu_li {
    float:right;
    width: 10em;
    margin-right:0.2em;
    text-align: center;
}

/* IE-Win (Holly hack) reads the list item line breaks, so lets hide those \*/
* html ul li { float: left; }
* html ul li a { height: 1%; }


.menusystem li:hover ul, .menusystem li.mouseHover ul { 
    display: block;
}

.menusystem li ul.child_menu_ul li a{
    /*
    color: #fff;
    */
    color: #fff;
    /* light blue */
/*  background: #7ba9c9;  */

        font-size: 80%;
    text-shadow: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2e6ea4;
    border-top: 0px;
}
.menusystem li ul.child_menu_ul li.first a
{
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 14px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 14px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #2e6ea4;
}

.menusystem li ul.child_menu_ul li.last a
{
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 14px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 14px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 14px;
}

.menusystem li ul.child_menu_ul li.only a 
{
    -moz-border-radius: 14px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 14px;

}

.menusystem li ul.child_menu_ul li a:hover {
    color: #ff0;
    background: #2e6ea4; 
}

.menusystem li.main_menu_li a
{
    color: #fff;
/*
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(100% 100% 90deg, #668eb8, #2e6ea4 );
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#668eb8), to(#2e6ea4));
*/
        background-color: #2e6ea4; 


    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    /*
    -moz-text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    -webkit-text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    -moz-border-radius: 14px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
*/
}

.menusystem li.main_menu_li a:hover {
    color: #ff0;
}

ul li.spaced
{   
    padding-bottom: 10px; 
    font-weight: normal;    
}
```

and the div with the html

```
    <div class="menusystem" id="site_nav">
        <ul class="main_menu_ul">
            <li class="main_menu_li"><a href="http://www.problemio.com/">Support</a>
            </li>

            <li class="main_menu_li"><a href="http://www.problemio.com/">Problems</a> 
                <ul class="child_menu_ul">
                    <li class="first"><a href="http://www.problemio.com/">Categories</a></li>
                    <li class="last"><a href="http://www.problemio.com/">Hello 5</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: It would help if you didn't change code on the server while people are  trying to answer.

Comment: @John I just wanted people to see the latest, but you are right. Btw, now I almost got the effect I wanted, but for some reason my blue bar only goes to half the screen lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two rules in the css managing dropdowns:

```
.menusystem li.main_menu_li a {
    background-color: #2E6EA4;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
.menusystem li.main_menu_li a:hover {
    color: #FFFF00;
}
```

Try moving background-color from `a` to `a:hover`

**Edit:** Missed the style for the dropdown:

```
.menusystem li ul.child_menu_ul li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2E6EA4;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    border-top: 0 none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-shadow: none;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2E6EA4; /* added this rule */
}
```

There's still an issue that the background for the head doesn't persist, but it's getting there.

Comment: just tried your suggestions and its live on the site, but it didn't quite work :(

Comment: I just made your latest update live, but it isn't really working and the blue bar is only going to half the screen - would you know how I can make it extend through the whole width? And the dropdown menus look funky :)

Comment: You've gone and changed something else, then? I suggest you put a representative sample of the HTML and CSS into a jsfiddle link; that way you and others can experiment with the styles more easily, without disturbing the website itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/3Qwk5/